# oAuth2 Playground YouTube Analytics API is not enabled for your project

Tags: oauth2-playground, youtube-analytics-api

I'm stuck with the following

I'm trying to make a call to YouTube Analytics API

I went to google's oAuth2 playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and in the first step I selected and authorized all the youtube related APIs as seen in the screenshot

[image: Authorize APIs]

Then on step 2 I exchanged the autorization code for tokens and on step 3, I send the following request to the API

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2007-05-01&end-date=2015-06-30&metrics=estimatedMinutesWatched%2Cviews%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained`

And what I get back is

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Analytics API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits", 
        "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Analytics API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.", 
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured", 
      }
    ]
  }
}`

But I have the YouTube Analytics API enabled.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To answer my own question, I solved my issue with the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24653407/2473413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We simply hadn't enabled this API for the default credentials used by the OAuth 2.0 Playground. As the other answer suggests you can always provide your own credentials with a project that has the Youtube Analytics API enabled. However I've also just enabled the API for the default/demo credentials so you can try again what you were doing and things should work now.

Comment: Thank you Nivco. I just tried and it works fine